# Macbook Pro Early 2015 (A1502) Keyboard not Working Sometimes

Tags: macbook-pro, keyboard, hardware, catalina

I'm currently using a macbook pro 2015 early, i updated to macOS Catalina 5 days ago, on the first day the keyboard was working fine, but they keyboard started freezing at random times (Only the power key works, others don't work) the touchpad works with force touch as normally.

- I've resetted the PRAM,NVRAM & SMC also
- Replugged the battery connector
- Replugged the Touchpad flex connector also

So i decided to downgrade to macOS Mojave, after downgrading the issue still continue as i was faced in the catalina also. Then i decided to replug the battery and i did that also along with re plugging the track pad flex connector. but nothing is fixed.

So if you are a Macbook pro 2015 early user and faced a similar problem like this please tell me what you did to fix this issue? Because on lots of the forums and youtube i saw some content that this is a common issue with Macbook pro 2015 A1502 models, and they fixed the issue with replacing the trackpad flex connector.
and i'm ready to go with their solution, to replace the flex connector and see.

Please help me if you faced a similar issue like this.

Thanks